# Episode of a show where people lose their memory in the afterlife

Tags: story-identification, tv, episode-identification

I'm sorry for the vagueness here: As a child (I would say definitely in the range 1995–2003) I watched an episode of a TV show which had as a plot point that people in the afterlife lost their memory of their life and those they had known. Definitely live-action, English-language and I'm pretty certain an adult cast. It would have been on British TV but could definitely have been a non-British production. I don't think I remember more (but feel free to ask in the comments) but that particular plot made an impression on me as a child.

I have a persistent feeling that it was a [*Wishbone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishbone_(TV_series)) episode but my searches didn't turn up anything promising. I do think it's likely that this was a show with each episode a self-contained plot (as is the case with *Wishbone*) rather than an ongoing plotline across episodes.

Comment: Did they arrive in an "afterlife" with no memories, or did they gradually lose them?  Or did they lose them when they reincarnated?

Comment: @DavidW I think 'gradually lose them in the afterlife' but not 100%. No reincarnation.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Valorum I looked at that before I posted; I'm not sure there are things on there I know which I haven't included.

Comment: Forgetting their life and loved ones was a fate of the dead in Tuonela (Finnish underworld) described in the *Kalevala* (Finnish national folklore/myth); the hero Väinämöinen was almost tricked by the Queen of the underworld into drinking a cup that would do the same to him.  I can't find any evidence that this was made into a live-action movie or TV show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People losing their memories in the afterlife was a plot point in [The Soldier and Death](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0710992/?ref_=ttep_ep1) - an episode of [The Storyteller](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092383/?ref_=ttep_ep_tt). The titular soldier had acquired a magic sack that would pull any being into it on command. He had cheated Death by pulling Death into the sack, and when he later decided to free Death, Death was afraid of him and he could not enter the afterlife. The soldier tried to trick his way into Heaven by giving the sack to a soul bound for Heaven and asking the soul to summon him into the sack after the soul has entered Heaven. His plan fails because there is no memory in Heaven and the soul forgets the soldier's instruction.

Comment: I think this is it! Sadly I can only find sections of it on YouTube, but thank you very much. I've been wondering about this one for a long, long time.